# Why requiredMessage not working with lang.properties (internationalization) jsf?

Tags: jsp, jsf

I am working on JSF with JSP as the view technology. I am trying to use internationalization in the below program.

This is **test.jsp**:

```
<head>
<f:loadBundle basename="com.infy.resource.Lang" var="label" />
</head>
<body>
    <f:view>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputText value="#{label.Enter_User_Id}" /><br>
            <h:inputText value="#{testBean.userId}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{label.Enter_User_Id}"/><br>
            <h:commandButton value="#{label.Login}" action="/test.jsp"/>

        </h:form>
        <h:messages style="color:red;"></h:messages>
    </f:view>
 </body>
```

This is my **Lang.properties** file:

```
Enter_User_Id=Enter User Id
Login=Login
```

But jsf is not able to read `requiredMessage` from the **Lang.properties** file.
Although it is able to read the label for `<h:outputText>`.

Can anyone suggest why it is not working ?

Is it because of the JSF Life cycle ?
 The required validations are done in Phase 3-Process validation and values are read from the Properties file in Phase 4-Update Model Phase. And if validations fail, the phases 4 and 5 are skipped and directly Phase 6-Render Response phase is reached to display the error massages.

Kindly correct me if I am wrong and suggest a way to read requiredMessage from Lang.properties file ?

Comment: It should work according to this blog post : http://kazed.blogspot.ch/2011/02/error-messages-for-required-fields-in.html

Comment: Thanks it is working!

Comment: Which JSF version are you concerned with though `test.jsp` implies JSF 1.x? `<f:loadBundle>` is superfluous in JSF 2.x. `var` is directly evaluated from `faces-config.xml`. That blog post assumes JSF 1.x.

Comment: I am using JSF 2.x but the view technology is jsp as already mentioned in the question. But writing the resource-Bundle in faces-config is working for me.